# Problema con .htaccess, error 500

Tags: php, html

Tengo este código en .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|dist|fla|inc|ini|log|psd|sh|sql|swp)|~)$">
    Order allow, deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>`
```

El problema es que sin ese código, me deja ingresar perfectamente al index.php, pero cuando lo coloco me aparece el problema.

> Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
> Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Uso xampp con apache y mysql

Mi codigo php todavia no tiene nada, es solo un h1 con un texto random.

Comment: Será que no tienes el modulo `headers` de apache instalado, que es el que interpreta el `FilesMatch` segun parece.

Comment: Ese es todo el código que tienes en el .htacces?

Answer (score 0):

No se que intentas hacer con esa regla.

Pero si lo que quieres es no permitir que se pueda acceder a archivos con esas extensiones

Cambia

```html
<FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|dist|fla|inc|ini|log|psd|sh|sql|swp)|~)$">
    Order allow, deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>`
```

Por

```html
RewriteRule \.(bak|config|dist|fla|inc|ini|log|psd|sh|sql|swp)$ index.php[NC,F,L]
```

Lo que hace este código es:

Cuando se intente acceder a cualquier archivo con la extensión incluida en la regla . Todas las solicitudes serán redireccionadas al `index.php`